# How to fill keywords field for MacOSX app, coded in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, keyword

How is it possible to fill some text in MacOSX Get Info screen's keywords field? For example, Contacts app there has keywords "Address Book" - how is it possible to do it from XCode?
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add an `MDItemKeywords` entry in your `Info.plist`. It seems that this is only used if you also have this entry in the localized `InfoPlist.strings` file however.